# In Rails 5.1.7, how to set default value from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently running Rails 5.1.7.

I'm trying to set a default value to a model based on a value in an associated field (two levels deep).

Here are the relevant models:

```rb
# app/models/assignment.rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  after_initialize  :default_values!

  private

  def default_values!
    self.fee ||= self.user.role.default_fee
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role, class_name: "UserRole", foreign_key: "user_role_id"
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end
```

And here's the user_roles table:

| id | label | access_level | default_fee | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | 0 | 0 | 2021-05-18 08:12:41.164286 | 2021-05-18 08:12:41.164286 |
| 2 | partner | 1 | 400 | 2021-05-18 08:12:44.990186 | 2021-05-18 08:12:44.990186 |
| 3 | associate | 2 | 350 | 2021-05-18 08:12:46.724820 | 2021-05-18 08:12:46.724820 |
| 4 | intern | 3 | 180 | 2021-05-18 08:12:48.421385 | 2021-05-18 08:12:48.421385 |

So, the goal is to set a default fee on the assignment level based on the `default_fee` value in the `user_roles` table.

As it stands, the following line `self.fee ||= self.user.role.default_fee` in the Assignment model renders a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'role' for nil:NilClass` error.

Any ideas as to how I could query this value at this stage?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `after_initialize` will call once a `new` object is created or you `find` an object. So, it needs to be handled with care. Now, if you init a new `Assignment` using `Assignement.new` - it'll try to run the callback, but as it's not associated with an user yet, so will give an error. Try `User.last.assignments.new`

Comment: Not I understand correctly... `User.last` will just give me any arbitrary `User` who just happens to be last in the list, right? Were as I’m trying to get this specific user mentioned in this specific assignment.

Comment: I used `User.last.assignments.new` this just to tell you how to initialize any Assignment. Let's say, you have an user with ID 1. So, if you want to init any assignment, then do `User.find(1).assignments.new`. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Well I figured it out by swapping the `after_initialize` with an `after_validation`. Thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing the `after_initialize` to an `after_validation` like this:

```rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  after_validation :default_values!

  private

  def default_values!
    self.case_owner ||= false
    self.fee        ||= self.user.role.default_fee
  end
end
```